# Regex to match strings not enclosed in macro

Tags: regex

In a development context, I would like to make sure all strings in source files within certain directories are enclosed in some macro "STR_MACRO". For this I will be using a Python script parsing the source files, and I would like to design a regex for detecting non-commented lines with strings *not enclosed* in this macro.

For instance, the regex should match the following strings:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
load_file("Hello World!");
```

But not the following ones:

```
std::cout << STR_MACRO("Hello World!") << std::endl;
load_file(STR_MACRO("Hello World!"));
// "foo" bar
```

Excluding commented lines containing strings seems to work well using the regex `^(?!\s*//).*"([^"]+)"`. However when I try to exclude non-commented strings already enclosed in the macro, using the regex `^(?!\s*//).*(?!STR_MACRO\()"([^"]+)"`, it does nothing more (seemingly due to with the opening parenthesis after STR_MACRO).

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: Match what you do not need, match and capture what you need. `re.sub(r'''^\s*//.*|STR_MACRO\("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\)|("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")''', lambda m: f'STR_MACRO({m.group(1)})' if m.group(1) else m.group(), text)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @wiktor, indeed your solution would work if I wanted the script to add the macro in case a string is found without it. But since there might be edge cases, I'd prefer the script to only detect those cases and report them. Can your approach be adujsted to only detect and not detect-and-replace?

Comment: Only if you use PyPi regex module - then you can use https://regex101.com/r/RHAlFp/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyPi regex module (that you can install with `pip install regex` in the terminal) you can use

```py
import regex

pattern = r'''(?:^//.*|STR_MACRO\("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\))(*SKIP)(*F)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"'''
text = r'''For instance, the regex should match the following strings:

std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
load_file("Hello World!");
But not the following ones:

std::cout << STR_MACRO("Hello World!") << std::endl;
load_file(STR_MACRO("Hello World!"));
// "foo" bar'''
print( regex.sub(pattern, r'STR_MACRO(\g<0>)', text, flags=regex.M) )
```

*Details*:

- `(?:^//.*|STR_MACRO\("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\))(*SKIP)(*F)` - `//` at the line start and the rest of the line, or `STR_MACRO(` + a double quoted string literal pattern + `)`, and then the match is skipped, and the next match search starts at the failure location
- `|` - or
- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`, then zero or more reptitions of a `\` and then any single char followed with zero or more chars other than a `"` and `\` chars, and then a `"` char

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dVHdS8MwEH/PX3HmpU0ZreBbtykqDEWGsgk@GDe6Nf2ALFeSK07Y/16zrShO9nTk7vdx90vzRRWaq66rNw1aAqtKtWWsyYiUNTAGGwRBeJMukiSOdvPX2XJ6ez97liF/X3ApPyI/kzLuHyLiUogwmj89vvgyEbtzMK/KSG2pd5ighdo4ysxaDYAqdVwEXIWtzmGT0bo6tAvUGj9rU4Ij64tLGXOUp@kaW4LRCPiD8gh4Q6vzC77vHMbK5HrINGb5sqi1Cv/CxJDdebpBOjFBo/45/IRwKnLW7CzD@yYJ8AKRwyrbB8EafxWFx/Nj167C/isGPqdfHVmOLq9F4KPyGQ6g0FnpxkfOVIDoum8). Output:

```
For instance, the regex should match the following strings:

std::cout << STR_MACRO("Hello World!") << std::endl;
load_file(STR_MACRO("Hello World!"));
But not the following ones:

std::cout << STR_MACRO("Hello World!") << std::endl;
load_file(STR_MACRO("Hello World!"));
// "foo" bar
```